# How can I check if a file is zip or not in R?

Tags: r, file, parsing, zip

I have tons of files like these:

```
temp1 <- tempfile()

temp2 <- tempfile()

download.file("https://my.pgp-hms.org/user_file/download/3658", temp1)

download.file('https://my.pgp-hms.org/user_file/download/3671', temp2)
```

One is a text (the one of size 16.1MB and the other is a zip with 5.6MB).

Please advise how can I check it on the fly? It's a public data set and I can't tell the authors to change the way they saved it a couple of years ago.

I have tried `summary(file(filename))$class` but it didn't help me.

I have read here on StackOverFlow that `read.table` can do this, it actually can but when it's zipped I get gibberish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built in R functionality for this, but you could try something similar to this. It's just a small custom function where it attempts to list the files contained within a zip file, if it can list the files it returns a value of TRUE. If it runs into an error, then the file cannot be unzipped and it returns a value of FALSE. It's not 100% accurate though, in that if you are testing something like a xlsx file you would  get a false positive.

```
is.zip <- function(filepath){
  result <- tryCatch({
              unzip(filepath, list = TRUE)
              return(TRUE)
            }, error = function(e){
              return(FALSE)
            })
  return(result)
}

is.zip(temp1)
is.zip(temp2)
```

Comment: It's not really a false positive though when xlsx are just zip files.

Comment: Maybe not from a purely technical standpoint, but contextually based on what is trying to be accomplished I would consider it a false positive. As the goal behind it's use in this case would be to try and identify which files would need to be unzipped before they can be read. I'm sure if one of the files happened to be a .xlsx, they would likely not want to unzip it. Hence it being a false positive for this use case.

Comment: But it literally is a zip file. You can build in a check against xlsx and not unzip those if you want but short of just checking if the file extension is .zip you are always going to have the possibility of these false positives

Comment: The trouble with checking the file extension is that with the method they used to download the file, the original file name is lost, including the file extension. So really the best option would be to search for a way to download the file while preserving the original name to check the extension. Again, my note about false positives is directed at the idea that the function can potentially return true on files without the .zip extension, since the goal was to identify files that need to be unzipped.